# How can I access the spelling check correction in LibreOffice Calc?

Tags: libreoffice-calc, ubuntu-15.10

LibreOffice Calc  5.0.4.2 on Ubuntu Linux 15.10 underlines misspelled words but does not display spelling check suggestions.

Is there a way to add spelling check suggestions to the right mouse click context menu?

[image]

Comment: What operating system and version of Office are you using?

Comment: I added the information about using the latest version of LO and Ubuntu Linux, @JimK.

Answer (score 3):

It should work.  Here is what it looks like on my system, using LO 5.0.3.2 on Windows 10:

[image]

I also tested this for LO 4.2.8.2 on Ubuntu 14.04 and it worked.

It may help to review the spellcheck settings using [this checklist](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/12733/which-options-are-required-to-obtain-spell-checking-in-multiple-languages/?answer=13855#post-id-13855).  Although the word is getting underlined, so I am not sure that is the problem.

Try upgrading to a newer version of LibreOffice and see if it works.

**EDIT:**

Now I see the problem.  It will not display the list of corrections if the row is too tall, or if the text in the cell is wrapped to multiple lines.

The behavior seems odd to me, and [the help](https://help.libreoffice.org/index.php?title=5.0/Common/Writing_Aids&Language=en-US&System=WIN&Version=5.0#Check_spelling_as_you_type) gives no indication of this.  You may want to consider [filing a bug report](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/QA/BugReport).  It occurs on all systems and versions that I tested.

Comment: Thank you @JimK! Interestingly your example of having just one misspelled word in a cell works. However, it does not work with a misspelled word as part of a sentence in a cell. Can you try to reproduce this problem?